# What do "X" lines mean on a signal?

Tags: spi, embedded

I was reading a specification sheet for a flash memory controller and came across a diagram for a particular command:

[image]

I was wondering what the "X" lines on the `SI` line actually mean?
Does it mean the line could be in any state, before `CE#` goes low, and we don't care about it at that point?

Comment: @AJN the X is used as a delimiter for information purposes ... how would you transmit data other than a 00 or FF if the SI line changed only between bytes?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_timing_diagram

Comment: I deleted my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't care or better: any state allowed